# Difference between ‘of’ and ‘in’ with ‘own life’

Tags: prepositions

I saw the expression '*he is a tourist of his own life*' in 
a Paul Auster's book. On the other hand, I also read the 
sentence 'I am a stranger in my own life'

So are these preposition used in a different way?

Or are they exchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of phrases where a writer could choose between two prepositions, and either one of them would sound fine in that context. This is one of them.

Our own life isn't a physical place, like a town, or a factory. As such, when we are trying to describe how we may not know ourselves completely, there's some leeway in how we might word that.

- *I am a stranger in my own life*

We often use the word *in* in conjunction with *stranger*, as in the title of Heinlein's classic book *Stranger in a Strange Land*.

- *I am a tourist of my own life*

The word *in* could have been used here, but I see no problem with *of*. When we tour a city, we can consider ourselves a tourist *of* that city, or a tourist *in* that city. Either preposition works, because, generally speaking, a tourist *of* Paris is a tourist *in* Paris.

Comment: I'm not sure Auster's *of* is being used in exactly that way. Verbs take Direct Objects, but nouns don't. Sometimes we want to show what the thing that the action described in the noun is done to. When we want to do this we use a preposition phrase with *of* - "a reader of books, an assassin of famous politicians, a purveyor of fine foods", for example.  So Auster's sentence here gives us the impression of the speaker actively visiting different parts of their life. The *in my own life* phrase doesn't really bring this out.